# Update Word bookmarks with formatted Excel data from Excel

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

The following code is intended to update Word bookmarks with formatted data from Excel, however the formatting doesn't come across and unsure why, would appreciate any suggestions.  The formatted data is text with certain works underlined.

```
Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
TodayDate = Format(Date, "mmmm d, yyyy")
Path = wb.Path & "\update_file.docx"

 'Create a new Word Session
Set pappWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")

 'Open document in word
Set docWord = pappWord.Documents.Add(Path)

 'Loop through names in the activeworkbook
For Each xlName In wb.Names
     'if xlName's name is existing in document then put the value in place of the bookmark
    If docWord.Bookmarks.Exists(xlName.Name) Then
    docWord.Bookmarks(xlName.Name).Range.Text = Range(xlName).Text  
    End If
Next xlName
```

Comment: *the formatting doesn't come across and unsure why* because a `range.Text` returns only the plain text within the cell :)

Comment: You can't carry formatting across from Excel to Word using the object model. Try copying the Excel range and pasting it in the Word range. For best results, test the various options in Word's paste option buttons and/or Paste Special. When you find the best approach, record a Word macro to get the exact Paste syntax.

Comment: @CindyMeister it should be possible (in theory) to do [character-wise iteration over the excel cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46248270/vba-for-excel-code-to-find-and-change-formatting-of-substrings-of-text-within-a) and mirror the formatting to Word. But that seems unnecessarily complicated when `Copy` and one of the several `Paste/PasteSpecial` options should suffice for most use-cases.

Comment: I must have misunderstood this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38573052/excel-vba-to-word-bookmark-with-excel-cell-format-retained?rq=1 where it seemed the OP had reported success using the object model with Range.Text, however the formatting he had in mind may have been number formatting rather than text formatting.

Comment: «the OP had reported success using the object model with Range.Text» Range(xlName).Text will carry over cell formatting (e.g. dates, currency) but not character formatting.

Comment: Thanks Cindy... I was looking for a button to push to approve but missed the checkmark!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this instead, using `Copy` and the (poorly-documented) `ExecuteMso` method. You need to use `Copy` against the range (in order to capture formatting) and then you can effectively do the same as the right-click *Paste + Keep Source Formatting* option:

[image]

```
If docWord.Bookmarks.Exists(xlName.Name) Then
    xlName.RefersToRange.Copy
    docWord.Bookmarks(xlName.Name).Select
    docWord.Application.CommandBars.ExecuteMso "PasteSourceFormatting"
End If
```

Alternatively, and this might be better because `ExecuteMso` is asynchronous and can result in timing issues:

```
xlName.RefersToRange.Copy
docWord.Bookmarks(xlName.Name).Range.PasteAndFormat 16 'wdFormatOriginalFormatting
```

[image]